# Assign date value (stored in variable) to date picker

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

Can any one suggest how to assign the date stored in variable to date picker?

I have created the function below and successfully stored a date in the `format` variable but I'm unable to assign the `format` variable value to date picker. Please suggest any idea what i am doing wrong here.

```
fun()
{
    format = $.datepicker.formatDate("dd-M-yy",new Date("2015-01-01"));
    alert(format)
    document.getElementById('render_SelectDate').value=format;
}
```

Comment: can any one suggest me how to assign variable value to date picker of javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just try this one. In format you can mention your date format

```
$('#daydatepicker').Zebra_DatePicker({
    format: 'm-d-Y',
    direction: -1,
    onSelect: function (date) {
    ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue(date);
    scope.$apply();
    }
});
```

ref : http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-dateFormat

Comment: Thanks a lot @ Sharathi RB

Answer (score 1):

I think the [setDate()](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#method-setDate) method is what you're looking for:

```
var date = new Date('2/20/2015');
$('#datepicker').datepicker('setDate', date);
```